# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-api, noclassdeffounderror, typetoken

I have been using [this](https://github.com/Ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/wiki) api. The API is a Java wrapper for Mailchimp API  with maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ecwid</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecwid-mailchimp</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I didn’t have trouble working with their API so far. But now I see this strange exception:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken
at com.ziprealty.subscription.MailChimpNewsSubscriptionProcessor.updateAllUnSubscribedEmails(MailChimpNewsSubscriptionProcessor.java:84)
at com.ziprealty.job.MailChimpSubscriptionProcessor.processTask(MailChimpSubscriptionProcessor.java:29)
at com.ziprealty.job.JobBase.run(JobBase.java:96)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
... 5 more
```

And here is the code for updateAllUnSubscribedEmails

```
public void updateAllUnSubscribedEmails( Date lastRunDate, String brandCode,Logger logger){


    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Entering mail chimp subscription processor in boardwalk for :" + brandCode);
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Last run date is :" + lastRunDate);
    System.out.println("Entering mail chimp subscription processor in boardwalk for :" + brandCode);

    try {

        MailChimpSubscriptionDAO subscriptionDAO = MailChimpSubscriptionDAO.INSTANCE;
        MailChimpSubscription  subscription= subscriptionDAO.getMailChimpSubscriptionByBrandCode(brandCode);

        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Subscription object is :"+ subscription);

        **ListMembersMethod listMembersMethod= new ListMembersMethod();**

        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"listMembersMethod object is :"+ listMembersMethod);
        listMembersMethod.status= MemberStatus.unsubscribed;
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"listMembersMethod.status object is :"+ listMembersMethod.status);
        listMembersMethod.apikey=mailChimpApiKey;
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"listMembersMethod.apikey object is :"+ listMembersMethod.apikey);
        listMembersMethod.id=subscription.getEmailListId();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"listMembersMethod.id object is :"+ listMembersMethod.id);

        listMembersMethod.since= lastRunDate;
        .
    .
    .
    .

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    } catch (MailChimpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
    }

    finally {

        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Finally block ...Try catch block ended");
    }

    logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"After finally Try catch block  without exception  ");


}
```

The code stops working at this line : 
        **ListMembersMethod listMembersMethod= new ListMembersMethod();**
It doesn’t even go to the Exceptions block at all. Only to the finally block.

This is the generated code by Intelij IDEA for the class **ListMembersMethod**:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package com.ecwid.mailchimp.method.v1_3.list;

import com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpAPIVersion;
import com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpMethod.Method;
import com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpObject.Field;
import com.ecwid.mailchimp.method.v1_3.list.HasListIdMethod;
import com.ecwid.mailchimp.method.v1_3.list.ListMembersResult;
import com.ecwid.mailchimp.method.v1_3.list.MemberStatus;
import java.util.Date;

@Method(
    name = "listMembers",
    version = MailChimpAPIVersion.v1_3
)
public class ListMembersMethod extends HasListIdMethod<ListMembersResult> {
    @Field
    public MemberStatus status;
    @Field
    public Date since;
    @Field
    public Integer start;
    @Field
    public Integer limit;

    public ListMembersMethod() {
    }
}


Intelij Idea has also generated the following code for hasHasListIdMethod :

//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package com.ecwid.mailchimp.method.v1_3.list;

import com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpMethod;
import com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpObject.Field;

public abstract class HasListIdMethod<R> extends MailChimpMethod<R> {
    @Field
    public String id;

    public HasListIdMethod() {
    }
}
```

The MailChimpMethod has the following code where it contains **TypeToken**
:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package com.ecwid.mailchimp;

import com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpAPIVersion;
import com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpObject;
import com.ecwid.mailchimp.MailChimpObject.Field;
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.GenericArrayType;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public abstract class MailChimpMethod<R> extends MailChimpObject {
    private final TypeToken<R> resultTypeToken = new TypeToken(this.getClass()) {
    };
    @Field
    public String apikey;

    public MailChimpMethod() {
    }

    public final MailChimpMethod.Method getMetaInfo() {
        for(Class c = this.getClass(); c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
            MailChimpMethod.Method a = (MailChimpMethod.Method)c.getAnnotation(MailChimpMethod.Method.class);
            if(a != null) {
                return a;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Neither " + this.getClass() + " nor its superclasses are annotated with " + MailChimpMethod.Method.class);
    }

    public final Type getResultType() {
        Type type = this.resultTypeToken.getType();
        if(!(type instanceof Class) && !(type instanceof ParameterizedType) && !(type instanceof GenericArrayType)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot resolve result type: " + this.resultTypeToken);
        } else {
            return type;
        }
    }

    @Documented
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
    public @interface Method {
        MailChimpAPIVersion version();

        String name();
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help on this. Couldn't figure out what the fix would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me sometime but I found the issue. I was working on two independent projects which are dependent on MailChimp API. However, I didn't have the maven dependency on one of the project and that was causing the problem.

So included the maven dependency on both projects, and it worked like a charm!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ecwid</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecwid-mailchimp</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

The MailChimp API Wrapper 2.0.1.0 depends on Guava 16.0.1 (see [mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/2.0.1.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ecwid/ecwid-mailchimp/2.0.1.0)). The `com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken` class is part of Guava 16.0.1 (see [central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar)).

Do you use Maven to build your project and if this is the case, can you compile/test your code without issues? Is Guava downloaded for the project? What do you see when running `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Freek. I found the issue. Please see the answer.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. An older version of Guava was pulled in by some lib. excluded it. Thanks, Freek!